# CORS Preflight Error in browser but postman request works

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm fairly new to world of angular so pardon if its a silly issue

I'm getting below error when trying to hit rest API via angular app

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/bean/user' from
> origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Here's my spring security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()   
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
        .httpBasic();   
    }
```

I tried adding cross-origin annotation to API but it didn't work either

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping(path="/bean/{name}")
public Bean path(@PathVariable String name) {
    return new Bean(name);
}
```

Someone suggested making the content type as text/plain so I tried that too but no luck. Here's an angular snippet that makes the call

```
executeBeanService(name: string) {
    let basicAuthHeaderString = this.createBasicAuthenticationHttpHeader();
    let header = new HttpHeaders ( {
      'Content-Type':'text/plain',
      Authorization: basicAuthHeaderString

    })

    return this.http.get<Bean>(`http://localhost:8080/bean/${name}`,
    {headers: header});
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From the title of your question it seems you are surprised that it works from postman. Browsers perform a cross origin check and Postman doesnt. Thats why.

Comment: Your spring application must send headers back to your web application telling it that a cross origin request is allowed. For example for the domain its coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is now resolved. The issue was the component scan. Since this is Spring Boot Application, the security configuration should be in the same package/sub-package the class in which @SpringBootApplication annotation is declared. In my case, the name of the package was different. Refactoring the package name and restarting the application resolved the issue.